# SQL data with new lines does not reflect in mvc view

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I have a stored procedure which returns a string as below.

```
 SET @TempMessage = 'Ok:  1 message in abc table' + char(13) + char(10)
    ....
    SET @TempMessage = @TempMessage +  ' Ok: 1 message in def table' + char(13) + char(10)
    ....
    SET @TempMessage = @TempMessage +  ' Ok: 1 message in ghi table'
    
    SELECT @TempMessage
```

I want the output in MVC view as below (3 lines)

```
Ok:  1 message in abc table
Ok:  1 message in def table
Ok:  1 message in ghi table
```

But the  output I am getting is just one line

> Ok:  1 message in abc table Ok:  1 message in def table Ok:  1 message in ghi table

In the controller, I tried to replace the string as below

```
var results = db.storedprocedure().FirstOrDefault()
viewmodel.outputmessage = results.replace(@"\r\n", Environment.NewLine)
```

but  it didn't work.

I have also tried

```
viewmodel.outputmessage = results.replace(@"\\r\\n", Environment.NewLine)
viewmodel.outputmessage = results.replace("\r\n", Environment.NewLine)
viewmodel.outputmessage = results.replace("\\r\\n", Environment.NewLine)
viewmodel.outputmessage = results.replace(@"\r\n", <br />)
```

There are similar posts like this, but none of the solutions in there do not seem to work out.

What can I try next?

Comment: I'm a little lost. Would the stored procedure not return multiple rows? 1 row per message and leave the representation up to the consumer? Then you can map each row into either an array in your viewmodel or concatenate them as needed into a single string separated by any breaks, linebreak, etc.. as needed.

Comment: Is there any constraints do it server side and just return a table with multiple strings?

Comment: My apologies. The stored procedure just returns a single string. I have amended the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML all newlines are treated as whitespace. To make them visible as line breaks you need to find the newlines, and in their place render a `<br />` tag, like in the following example View code:

```
@{
    var str = "--1--/r/n--2--/r/n--3--";
    var lines = str.Split(new[] { "/r/n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        @(line)<br />
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. But I am wondering why results.Replace(@"\r\n", "<br />"); in the controller method didn't work

Comment: First of all your syntax seems incorrect, it should be `results.replace(@"\r\n", "<br />")`. Also, if you used `@outputmessage` then that would HTML-Encode anything you are printing, meaning that your `<br />` are actually sent to the browser as `&lt;br /&gt;`. That can be prevented by using `@Html.Raw(outputmessage)` but then any special markup coming form your database will be interpreted by the browser (e.g. `<b>text</b>` becomes **text**, and any `<script>`-parts would start being exuecuted in the browser).